# Excluding files in Azure Data Studio when they don't have a file extension

Tags: data

I need to SFTP files generated every 15 minutes up to an external SAAS product.

The problem is the app generating these files has a hard lock on them. It monitors realtime and keeps appending. The target system doesn't actually need those files. But it does need all the other files in the folder.

The files don't have an extension, so I can't pattern-match the ones to copy up.

Is there any way to do this in ADF natively?

Or if it can't do that, can I run a Python script or PowerShell and pass the file list I want it to send back to ADF?

The files have RTA in the name, so I'm sure I can regex that string in Python. Passing that list back to ADF for the pipeline job is the bit I have no clue about.

Full disclosure - I wasn't sure where the right place to ask this one was, so I also asked here:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334408/how-do-i-exclude-files-in-adf-when-they-dont-have-a-file-extension